# SELECT INTO OUTFILE with UPDATE field in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi how can I put the following statements into one query:

1. Select certain mysql data
2. Export these data
3. Update the status column of these exported data with status "ex"

I tried this but it did not work:

```
UPDATE TableA SET status = "ex"
OUTPUT columnA, columnB
INTO OUTFILE "C:\\my.csv"
```

Comment: It is not possible to combine a `SELECT` statement, an `UPDATE` statement, and an `INTO OUTFILE` clause into a single MySQL statement.

Comment: @kampit are you sure? So how would you combine it with one db request? I even was thinking to set an sql  array for the ids to process afterwards the ids but I could not find an solution.

Comment: Start a transaction. Select into outfile. Update the same rows that were selected. Commit the transaction.